# oracle regexp_substr for random occurrence of a pattern

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

Hi I need to find a pattern which randomly occur in a string in any order

The values in a column may be like these

```
'k=34,n=WER-RTN,l=hy33,z=device'

'k=34,l=hy33,z=device,n=WER-RTN'

'n=WER-RTN,l=hy33,z=device,k=34'
```

I need to pick up the value against n= till ',' else if it occurs at the end till last.
but n can occur any where in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `WER-RTN` value, you could extract that value with a regular expression like this one:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT 'k=34,n=WER-RTN,l=hy33,z=device' text FROM dual
           UNION
           SELECT 'k=34,l=hy33,z=device,n=WER-RTN' text FROM dual
           UNION
           SELECT 'n=WER-RTN,l=hy33,z=device,k=34' text FROM dual)
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(text,'(n=.+?,)|(n=.+?$)'),'n='),',')
FROM t
```

If you're using Oracle 11g or superior you could simplify it a bit:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR (text, '(^|,)n=([^,]+)', 1, 1, '', 2)
```

Comment: A somewhat simplified select clause would be `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (text, '(^|,)n=([^,]+)', 1, 1, '', 2) FROM t`.

Comment: @collapsar what does the last parameter  (2) mean?

Comment: @pablomatico The last parameter is the number of the subexpression. `0`represents the complete match,`1` ... `9` refer to the match portion corresponding to the `n`th subexpression in parentheses ( equivalent to `\1`...`\9` in other regex engines ).

Comment: @collapsar it's not working for me, i get ORA-00939: too many arguments for function. I'm using Oracle 10gR2. Is it a new feature in newer versions?

Comment: @pablomatico Yes, you are correct, the subexpression parameter has been introduced with 11g.

Comment: Thanks @collapsar! I just tried it on 11g and it worked! I'll include that in my answer